# pdocument.save() taking more time

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox, smb

I have used PDFBOX 1.8.16 & FONTBOX 1.8.16 and created PDF from String.
The program is like any other PDFBOX program just a difference is that i am using SMB for saving the created pdf document on shared folder.
Sample code is as below

```
authentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3);

        smbScreenshotFile = new SmbFile("smb:" + "//TestPath/example.pdf", authentication);
        smbScreenshotFile = new SmbFile(smbFileName, authentication);
        out = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbScreenshotFile);

        pdocument.save(out);
```

Now the String that i am converting to pdf can become very big. it can also create pdf with 2000+ pages. The problem is that in local even 2000+ page pdf is getting created in 10-15 seconds but if i use SMB and try to store pdf on shared folder it is taking more than half hour to save, especially this command is taking all of the time
    pdocument.save(); Need solution for this i cant store pdf on local machine.

Comment: How fast is the shared folder? If it's on a slow machine/slow storage then it will ofcourse be slow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance: Very slow file copying to Windows network using JCIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119489/performance-very-slow-file-copying-to-windows-network-using-jcif)