# Using jCIFS in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, smb, jcifs

I am using jCIFS (SMB) to access network drives from a java desktop application. I notice that the first access takes around 6 seconds but, following that, there is very little delay.

However, when I connect to a network path on a new thread, the 6 second delay on first access is present again.

I assume that the delay is due to the initial authentication and that a session token (or something similar) is stored in the current thread.

Is there a way to share the session between more than one thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post [JCIFS: file retrieval is too slow to be usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533653/jcifs-file-retrieval-is-too-slow-to-be-usable).

Using the setting, `jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.resolveOrder", "DNS");`, made the connect faster and resolved my problem.