# Performance: Android JCIFS file reading is slow

Tags: android, performance, optimization, jcifs

First of all, I saw an existing question ([JCIFS: file retrieval is too slow to be usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533653/jcifs-file-retrieval-is-too-slow-to-be-usable)), but it was for Java, not Android, and none of the suggested answers worked.

I created a default project for Android SDK 25 (7.1.1) in Android Studio 2.3, linked the library with `compile 'jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17'`, and typed the following simple test code. The result is below the code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.util.loglevel", "3");
    //jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.dfs.disabled", "false");
    //jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.resolveOrder", "DNS");

    try
    {
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", ID, PASSWORD);
        final SmbFile smb = new SmbFile("smb://192.168.XX.XX/Share/FileName", auth);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Test Start");

                for(int i = 1000; i<10000; i+=1000)
                    measure(i);

                Log.d(TAG, "Test End");
            }

            private void measure(int bufferSize)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "=====Buffer: " + bufferSize + "============");
                try
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    int read = 0;
                    InputStream str = smb.getInputStream();
                    long start = System.nanoTime();

                    while(read < 1000000)
                        read += str.read(buffer);

                    long end = System.nanoTime();
                    str.close();
                    float time = (float) ((end - start) / 1000000000d);
                    float speed = (float) read / 1048576 / time;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Time:" + time + ", size =" + read);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Speed =  " + speed + "MB/s");
                }
                catch(IOException exc)
                {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, exc.toString());
    }
}
```

Result

```
Test Start
=====Buffer: 1000============
Time:2.210785, size =1000000
Speed =  0.43137363MB/s
=====Buffer: 2000============
Time:1.4158936, size =1000000
Speed =  0.6735495MB/s
=====Buffer: 3000============
Time:1.0556641, size =1002000
Speed =  0.9051948MB/s
=====Buffer: 4000============
Time:0.7543335, size =1000000
Speed =  1.2642609MB/s
=====Buffer: 5000============
Time:3.6557617, size =1000000
Speed =  0.26086885MB/s
=====Buffer: 6000============
Time:3.292389, size =1002000
Speed =  0.2902396MB/s
=====Buffer: 7000============
Time:2.9179688, size =1001000
Speed =  0.32715496MB/s
=====Buffer: 8000============
Time:2.462616, size =1000000
Speed =  0.38726068MB/s
=====Buffer: 9000============
Time:3.9379272, size =1008000
Speed =  0.24411413MB/s
Test End
```

Read speed is about 0.2MB/s ~ 1.2MB/s. The device is connected to a 150Mbps Wi-Fi, so, theoretically it can achieve above 10MB/s. The SMB server is not slow either. When I copied the file to a laptop, the read speed was about 30MB/s.

Why is this so slow? What should I check? Why is the read speed about 5 times higher (1.2MB/s) if the buffer size is 4000?

By the way, I have tested copying the same file with other commercial apps. File Commander, Asus File Manager showed similary low speed, ES File Explorer showed about 2MB/s, and Solid Explorer showed about 5MB/s. Since I am pretty sure that all of them use JCIFS (albeit perhaps slightly different versions of it), there must be a way to achieve at least 5MB/s as Solid Explorer does.

Answer (score 2):

After using WireShark (network analysis tool) on the Windows computer, I have found that no matter which buffer size I set, the read SMB command always gives 4286 bytes to the Windows computer. It seems that `SmbFileInputStream.java` is using the max buffer size from the server.

But when I saw the packets from Soild Explorer, it was 32768 bytes. So, I decompiled Solid Explorer's APK (it was of course obfuscated), and saw the `SmbFileInputStream.java` file inside of it (that file belongs to JCIFS). It seems that the developers of Solid Explorer has modified that file, and set a bigger `readSize`. So, I tried a similar thing. And then I achieved 5MB/s for the same code above.

Since JCIFS comes with LGPL, the fact that Solid Explorer is using a modified JCIFS without disclosing the source code is a violation of JCIFS' licence. But, oh well, it seems a lot of Android app developers ignores licence of the libraries they use anyway. They do not even properly credit the open-source libraries they used.

Comment: Maybe they used the patch mentioned in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with: `jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.dfs.disabled", "true");`

In my case (though Java) it was helpful for slow connection. By default it is `false`

Only problem for me is that I'm not sure will that property "break" something else which is working fine..

Comment: Yeah, if you look closely, I had already tried that in my original code sample. As I had written, the problem was the small message size, which introduced  more number of roundtrips and overheads.

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch for large buffer size reading:

- https://github.com/kohsuke/jcifs/issues/11
- https://github.com/kohsuke/jcifs/tree/master/patches
- https://jcifs.samba.org/src/patches/LargeReadWrite.patch:

From inside the README:

> This patch adds two SMBs that supposedly improves read and write
>   performance considerably. Unfortunately it's not crystal clear that
>   all implementation properly support the commands. Note that in
>   addition to this patch an '& 0xFFFF' needs to be added in
>   SmbTransport.java:doRecv:~437 to appear as:
>
> int size = Encdec.dec_uint16be( BUF, 2 ) & 0xFFFF;
>
> although this change has been made in 1.2.7.

Not sure if this works with Android, but the solution could be similar.